# URLDownloadToFile Returns E_ABORT C++

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to download a file for use. my code is:

```
TCHAR url[] = TEXT("https://fakeurl.net/important.dll ");
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
HRESULT res = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL);
Sleep(10000);
```

This returns[image: E_ABORT Operation Aborted]
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you giving it the name of your current directory?

Comment: what? can you rephrase?

Comment: It needs a path to a file and not a directory. You are passing it a directory.